# How to run jacocoTestReport when including Android instrumental tests?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, reporting, jacoco

My Android app contains both Unit and Instrumental tests, and I'd like to generate a coverage report using the JaCoCo plugin (and then finally porting to [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io) ) . But I cannot seem to run `gradlew jacocoTestReport` on my local machine, because I don't have a emulator or device that connects to Android Studio. The error and complete log is up at https://pastebin.com/c7vcwseF .

Here's the portion of my app's `build.gradle` that contains the task definition:

```
# ...
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
}

coveralls {
    jacocoReportPath 'build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/jacocoTestReport.xml'
}
# ...
```

I am using the `org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.2` plugin in my Android project.

So how would one run `gradlew jacocoTestReport` and generate the report locally?

Comment: This was the solution worked for me:
https://medium.com/wandera-engineering/android-kotlin-code-coverage-with-jacoco-sonar-and-gradle-plugin-6-x-3933ed503a6e